# Php Session not working properly in CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

My website was working properly in last year, we need better performance of the website then we have run two script on Centos 6.9 server
1) mysqltunner script
2) Engintron Nginx v1.8.5

It has been after installed then Some time down website, now website is working.

**Problem: multiple users login same time with different system then some user account display all thing to another user data,**

for example : Mark is login with our username and password, Peter is already login then some time(2min after) Mark moved to Peter a

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Engintron  and  micro-caching, if you disable engintron session will work normally